# EasyMock and testing Protected Methods

Tags: java, easymock

Trying to use EasyMock to test if a protected method gets called, not sure if this is the best way to do it ... but given the below, how can I tell that didIgetCalled() actually was called when callMe() was called?

```
public Class testMe(){
    public int callMe(){
        if(true){
            didIgetCalled();
        }
        return 1;
    }
    protected int didIgetCalled(){
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you can't do this, you can only check whether public methods have been called. When doing unit testing try to think of it a little bit more in terms of 'black-box' testing, don't worry so much about what happens internally, just worry about the inputs and outputs, and interactions with other objects.

Comment: Ok... Kinda knew that, but was wondering if there was a way to test if a certain method was called or not from a parent method, would be a nice to have.

Comment: Yep, usually it is sufficient to not verify exactly which methods were called, but rather only if the state of the Object after the call is what you expect it. So in your example if you would verify the return-value of callMe(), which method internally was involved is not relevant from the outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way you can test the method without using EasyMock, however my recommendation is that: If it's not public, don't write a test for it

```
Method method = testMe.class.getDeclaredMethod("didIgetCalled", new Class[]{});
method.setAccessible(true);
testMe testClass = new testMe();
int invoke = (Integer) method.invoke(testClass);
assertEquals(2,invoke);
```

**I know that this will not entirely solve your problem but it's a start** :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

You could keep the same package name for your test class as that of the class under test. That way if your class under test say `MyClass.java` is in `src` directory with package name `com.abc.mypackage` then you your test class say `MyClassTest.java` could be in `test` directory with same package name. See image below:

[image]